# I need clarification with hmac-sha1 sample

Tags: hmacsha1

I am new to hmac-sha1.  I have a couple of questions about the sample.

```
/*
  inputs:
  NSData *keyData;
  NSData *clearTextData
*/

uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};

CCHmacContext hmacContext;
CCHmacInit(&hmacContext, kCCHmacAlgSHA1, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);
CCHmacUpdate(&hmacContext, clearTextData.bytes, clearTextData.length);
CCHmacFinal(&hmacContext, digest);

NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

1. What is `clearTextData`?  Is it the source string in `NSData` object form?
2. What is `kData`? Is it the source data to be encoded?
3. Where is the secret key? (Is that `kData`?)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jens.mooseyard.com/2009/04/mycrypto-library-now-alpha-testing/) is a good discussion of what you are trying to do.